# Почему не работает System.ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image: System.ValueTuple не работает]

Использую последний релиз VS 2017 + .NET Framework 4.6.2
Компилятор не подцепляет `System.ValueTuple.dll`, хотя должен (это же C# 7).
Ставить `System.ValueTuple.dll` пакетом nuget не хочу, так как выходному бинарнику не нужны лишние зависимости.
Примечательно что по пути

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn` 
лежит `System.ValueTuple.dll`,

а по пути `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2`
его нет.

Пробовал удалять и переустанавливать .NET Framework и VS 2017, не помогло.
Пытался шаманить с добавлением `System.ValueTuple.dll` в `\Reference Assemblies` и прописыванием в `FrameworkList.xml`, то же не помогло.
Пробовал прописывать в `csc.rsp`, `csc.exe.config`, не помогло.
И при всем этом `csi.exe` спокойно работает с `ValueTuple`.
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: а в настройках проекта нет какой-нибудь галочки?

Comment: Если нет в Reference Assemblies, значит класс - не часть фреймворка, и вам придется или руками добавить референс, или поставить nuget package.

Comment: Это странно, но он действительно не часть фреймворка. Даже если поставить DevPack 4.6.2

Comment: не часть фреймворка? Как? Это же часть C# 7?

Comment: @ДаниилДемидко в следующих версиях обещали добавить. Пока System.ValueTuple есть только в виде nuget-пакета. Возможно будет еще и targeting pack.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно установить пакет `NuGet System.ValueTuple`. Открываете `Package Manager Console` и пишете там команду:

> Install-Package "System.ValueTuple"

После этого Ваш код заработает. Ссылка на источник: [Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383064/5275890)