# Как сделать Distinct по нескольким полям в классе?

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс

```
class ClassidIntanceid
{
    public string i_classid { get; set; }
    public string ui_id { get; set; }
    public string i_instanceid { get; set; }
    public string i_market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public float ui_price { get; set; }
}
```

Также есть список, в котором множество таких экземпляров класса.

```
List<ClassidIntanceid> classintance = new List<ClassidIntanceid>();
```

Стоит задача сделать Distinct по двум полям - `i_classid` и `i_instance_id`

Если сделать classinstance.Distincs - то он начинает искать дубли по всем полям. В сети нашел одно решение через `MoreLinq`, но хочется сделать это стандартными средствами. Скорее всего как то через `IEqualityComparer` можно это сделать.

Comment: @Grundy там одна пропертя, а не несколько

Comment: @PavelMayorov, какая разница-то? :-) суть одна и та же, ответы даже совпадают с теми, что уже тут: IEqualityComparer, GroupBy, MoreLinq

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать такое расширение от автора [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/489421):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Самое удачное решение `Distinct` по полю класса, которое я смог найти для себя.

В вашем случае используйте его так:

```
var query = classintance.DistinctBy(p => new { i_classid, i_instance_id });
```

Comment: Это по идее и есть DistinctBy из MoreLinq.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Если перейти по ссылке, то там Джон указал, что этот код сейчас в составе библиотеки MoreLinq. 
Лично я не пользуюсь этой библиотекой, мне хватает стандартных средств в большинстве случаев, но именно функционал `DistinctBy` порой бывает очень нужен. Надеюсь его добавят в стандартную библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
classintance.GroupBy(o => (o.i_classid, o.i_instanceid)).Select(g => g.First())
```

или даже просто

```
classintance.GroupBy(o => (o.i_classid, o.i_instanceid), (key, g) => g.First())
```

Это может быть немного менее эффективно, чем решение из MoreLinq.

И да, можно написать кастомный `IValueComparer` тоже.

---

Если вы пользуетесь старым компилятором, вам придётся перейти к менее эффективным анонимным классам:

```
o => new  { o.i_classid, o.i_instanceid }
```

Но если вы работаете со свежей версией компилятора, [проблем быть не должно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644251/10105).

Comment: "System.ValueTuple`2" не определен и не импортирован

Comment: у меня netf 4.5

Comment: @Zevra: Ну так импортируйте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644251/10105

Comment: @VladD, а можете пояснить, почему вы считаете что кортежи эффективнее классов? В принципе, теперь с новыми фишками для кортежей, нужда в анонимных классах отпадает (они, вроде, тоже неизменяемые, на сколько я помню)?

Comment: @Андрей: Только тем, что не грузят сборщик мусора, они ж всё-таки value type.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правы, это можно сделать через `IEqualityComparer`, например так:

Создайте класс компарера:

```
class InstanceidComparer : EqualityComparer<ClassidIntanceid>
{
    public override bool Equals(ClassidIntanceid x, ClassidIntanceid y)
    {
        return x.i_classid == y.i_classid && x.i_instanceid == y.i_instanceid;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(ClassidIntanceid obj)
    {
        return obj.i_classid.GetHashCode() * 17 + obj.i_instanceid.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

затем создаете экземпляр этого класса и передаете его в `Distinct`:

```
var comparer = new InstanceidComparer();
var result = classintance.Distinct(comparer);
```

Минус этого подхода - для сравнения по разным свойствам нужны разные классы компарера